# vue + vuetify related v-autocomplete fields

Tags: api, vue.js, promise, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my setup I'm using the latest version of VueJS + Vuetify.

In my application I have a vue component which on the template side has two v-autocomplete elements per entry in a list.
The items of the first autocomplete of each entry are populated from an external API call via. axios.

The second autocomplete element in each entry/row is supposed to be populated depending on the value selected in the first one.
So when the user selects a Country from the autocomplete list, an API call should be initiated and the second autocomplete element (Cities) should receive the correct options.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I tried hooking up my getCities() method to the second autocomplete items property, but since my method is returning a Promise, that's not working out.

Note here, that I can‘t simply assign the value returned by the promise (e.g
`this.cities = res.data`
) to a property, since my autocomplete fields are dynamic/extensible.

I‘ve created a fiddle here which represents what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/mgto7uea/3 (note, one API call is relying on a local data source).

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the first autocomplete and fetch the cities there:

```html
<template>
  <!-- cities autocomplete -->
  <v-autocomplete v-model="item.city" :items="cities" item-text="name">
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
  //...
  getCities(country) {
    axios.get('https://cities-api.local/rest/v2/' + country).then(resp => {
      this.cities = resp.data //assuming the response data returns the citites
    })
  }
},
watch: {
  gItems: {
    deep: true,
    handler(data) {
      this.getCities(data[0].country)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I already mentioned, this is unfortunately not going to solve it. Given that the amount of autocomplete fields is variable (variable amount of 2x v-autocomplete), it‘s not sufficient to assign the cities to a “this.cities” property. Any more suggestions?